# PHP jquery data passing to object

Tags: jquery, oop, object

Can someone please explain to me how the data passed to jquery object, so it's then accessible from jquery.

I.E.:

PHP script:

```
// $isrc variable is added by me to existing grid..
    $isrc = isrc();
    $grid->isrc = $isrc;
    $grid->load();
```

object declared in js:

```
$.fn.loadGrid = function(user_opts) {
        return this.each(function() {

            // setup DEFAULT options
            var opts = $.extend({
                order_by : "",          // sql order by
                .....
            },user_opts);
            var $grid = $(this);
            ..some stuff to do....
        });
    }
    ... some additional function to call....
});
```

so how do i access $isrc data?
calling it after:

```
        var $grid = $(this);
        var isrc = $grid.data().isrc;
```

comes back as unidentified...

sorry i'm quite new to object oriented programming, although i did study Java and VB few years ago..

or at lease give me a link to a tutorial re subject?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the value from PHP to jQuery then do whatever you want with it. 
You want to echo the value in php (Ideally in a JSON format). Then use jQuery $.ajax to call the page, get the data and then do whatever you want with it in javascript.

Here are some easy to follow Video tutorials for PHP & jQuery. It covers EVERYTHING from the basics to more advanced concepts including OOP.

Best of all.. They are FREE!

http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=11 <-- PHP Tutorials (200 Part Series)
http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32 <-- jQuery Tutorials (200 Part Series)

If you go over these and learn from them. You will be able to do almost ANYTHING with PHP & jQuery.

Comment: thanks for replying! data is passed from php to jquery as - echo json_encode($grid->data); - i can access native grid data, but not the one i added manually - that's what i need. i will have a look at the tutorials you suggested - thank you